# Is it possible to inherit from a linux driver with minimal modifications?

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, device-tree

I'm using the [`spidev`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/spi/spidev) driver to expose a few SPI devices connected to an ARM SoC to userspace through a character device.

Placing suitable nodes in the device tree will generate the devices as expected. However, the compatibility in the device tree in this case is set using the name "spidev". This causes the driver to issue a warning about the driver compatibility not being explicitly set. The warning is issued [here](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/spi/spidev.c#L727) during the device probe, and as I understand it is based on the device tree node being present but not being listed as a suitable `.compatible` in the `of_device_id` struct.

I'd now like to fix this problem (the problem behind the warning). The obvious thing to do would be to patch `spidev.c` to have an extra `.compatible` line with my device(s) added appropriately.

Better, IMO, would be to write a minimal driver that uses all the functionality of `spidev` but presents the correct `of_device_id` structure. This way small tweaks to `spidev.c` aren't going to break the solution, unlike a patch which would be rather fragile.

My question then is this: How minimal a driver can I write to expose an `spidev` equivalent given that it's already been written? Can I effectively inherit from the driver and just change minimal parts of it (the `of_device_id` struct)?

I can't find anything on the web talking about this, and `spidev` has no associated header file to draw on, so I'm not optimistic, but more than likely I've missed something.